# Autocomplete and suggestions don't work

Tags: neovim, lsp, lazyvim

My autocomplete is not working. First, let me say that I'm a noob using lazyvim but I'm so enthusiastic about it and I'm trying to learn. Trying to code in any language I don't get any language recommendations from the autocomplete, or corrections. It's a fresh installation and I installed the language packages through Mason but when I type anything on a new file I don't get any suggestions or corrections. I'm trying to use to code HTML but can't get any corrections or suggestions from the program. I want, for example, to type "html5" and get the necessary lines of code, or to type head and get the opening and closing brackets but the program is not giving me any
Any ideas? Thanks for your help and happy holidays
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file Perhaps? We can’t do anything without a minimal reproducible example. Please [edit] with more details

Comment: The LSP configuration is language dependent. It would be good if you could tell us for which language(s) you seek cide completion.

Comment: Could you precise what kind of support you would expect to write html? Maybe could you be interested by the [emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The [emmmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) plugin provides support for html tag insertion:

`html:5`<kbd>Ctrl y</kbd>`,` expand into:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

`div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a`<kbd>Ctrl y</kbd>`,` expand into:

```html
    <div id="page">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It was a silly fault. I just have to open a file as .html/css/jsx and I get the proper text recommendations. So I create a file>save as filename.html and it starts working. Thanks anyway. Happy Christmas guys

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Merry Christmas ans happy new year to you :-)